# Не работает window.onresize, если вызываем класс второй раз

Tags: javascript

Добрый день. Не срабатывает функция  windowResizeHandler - отвечает за перестройку элементов если размер меньше 768px для первого вызова  (demo1).
Подскажите почему так происходит?

windowResizeHandler(tabSelector, toggleSelector) {

```
const currentWidth = document.documentElement.scrollWidth;
const fragmentArea = document.createDocumentFragment();
const currentActiveTab = this.area.querySelector(tabSelector);
const currnetActiveToggle = this.area.querySelector(toggleSelector);
const self = this;
let fragmentCheck = false;
[].forEach.call(this.tabs, (tab, i) => {
  if (currentWidth < 768) {
    self.area.children[0].insertBefore(tab, self.toggle[i].nextElementSibling);
  } else {
    fragmentArea.appendChild(tab);
    fragmentCheck = true;
  }
});
if (fragmentCheck && currentWidth > 768) {
  this.area.appendChild(fragmentArea);
  if (!(currentActiveTab && currnetActiveToggle)) {
    this.toggle[0].classList.add(this.toggleStateActive);
    this.tabs[0].classList.remove(this.tabHide);
    this.tabs[0].setAttribute(this.ariaSelected, 'true');
  }
}
```

}

https://codepen.io/nsobolev/pen/LmEbVe

Comment: 1. Воспроизводимый пример должен быть в самом вопросе. 2. Этот пример должен быть минимальным. Разбираться в тонне кода не стал, но показалось очень подозрительным, что функция `windowResizeHandler` рассчитывает на параметры `tabSelector`, `toggleSelector`, в качестве которых по факту являются объект события и `undefined`. Думаю, стоит начать с исправления функции `resizeWindow`.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался.